# Can you delete android play store app and use the package name?

Tags: android, package

I have an app that's currently on the Google Play store with the package name x.x.x. I want to delete this app but I want to reuse the package name for a new app that I will be uploading in its place.

Is it possible to just delete the old app, and upload the new app with the existing package name?

Thanks,

Comment: why doesn't google allow you to delete or even hide unpublished apps? The whole reason I'm doing this is because you can't change an app from free to paid. its such a pain...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because you can't really delete an app. It will only be disabled. So this app will still be visible in your developer console.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't delete an app from Google Play once you have published it. In your case, I guess you could just upload a new app with same package name and it would overwrite the old app. But you would have to upload it as a "newer" version of your existing app (i.e new app version in manifest). But this method isn't the most user friendly, because old users would be offered completely new program as an "update" to the old one.

Answer (score -1):

You can write new appwith this same Package name and use it as update for old one. But i do not know what will happen if You first delete old application.

Comment: No, you can't delete the first one and add a completely new one. See my answer.